# Page Editor not supporting for mobile site

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

After selecting specific component(eg. sitecore link field text), whole block is being selected?

but I want to edit the particular component on user click.

```
 <ul>
            <li>                
                <sc:Link ID="hlItem1Link" runat="server" Field="Item 1 Title Link">
                    <span class="health-plans-image-container" id="item1Icon" runat="server"></span>
                    <br />                    
                    <asp:Literal ID="frItem1TitleLink" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </sc:Link>
            </li>
            <li>...<li>
</ul>
```

What should I do? Am I making any mistake?

Comment: Hi, can you confirm what you mean by page editor not supporting for mobile? I don't think the page editor is made for editing sites on mobile.

Check this out for device simulation: http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/11/Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-6-6-Features-Device-Simulation.aspx I also recommend reviewing how to go about making responsive sitecore sites :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and yes it is requirement to support page editor in mobile mode, thats why I have asked this question. And Site is not responsive also.

Comment: What version of sitecore are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from sdn.sitecore.net. Found this pdf labelled: "Sitecore CMS 7.0 or later Browser Configuration Reference"

> Sitecore currently supports the following web browsers:
>
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer 8, 9, and 10.
> - Mozilla Firefox 17 and later.
> - Google Chrome 25 and later.
> - Apple Safari 6 for Mac OS

I believe page editor is **NOT** supported on mobile, currently.

Answer (score 0):

The question as currently written isn't clear, and I agree with [Anicho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199640/anicho)'s point that Page Editor is not officially supported for mobile, but reading the question I wonder if this phrase

> After selecting specific component(eg. sitecore link field text), whole block is being selected?
>   but I want to edit the particular component on user click.

means that you're seeing the UI selecting an entire Rendering or Sublayout when you click it, rather than a particular field in that control that you want to edit?

Page Editor has two modes for what happens when you click stuff. In "Designing" mode clicking inside a UI component selects the whole thing, and lets you do stuff like move it, delete it or set its properties. In "Editing" mode, clicking inside a component selects the fields you click and lets you change their values.

Perhaps you have "Designing" mode on, and "Editing" mode off? If so, check the Page Editor ribbon. To be able to change the values of individual fields, you need to ensure the "Editing" checkbox on the "View" ribbon tab is selected:

[image: Changing the Page Editor Mode options]

I tend to work with only one or the other on at a time, but it's valid to enable both at the same time.